# Select SQL Inner Join and Omit Certain Record

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables with following data:

Table A

```
ID       DESC
1        One
2        Two
3        Three
```

ID is primary key

Table B shows the action I did to ID in table A

```
NO       ACTION       ID       DATETIME
1        ADD          1        2012-01-01 00:00:00
2        ADD          2        2012-01-01 00:00:00
3        ADD          3        2012-01-01 00:00:00
4        DELETE       2        2012-01-01 01:00:00
5        EDIT         1        2012-01-01 02:00:00
6        EDIT         3        2012-01-01 03:00:00
7        DELETE       1        2012-01-01 03:00:00
8        REVIVE       2        2012-01-01 04:00:00
9        EDIT         2        2012-01-01 05:00:00
```

NO is primary key

Here's the summary:

ID 1: ADD on 2012-01-01 00:00:00, EDIT on 2012-01-01 02:00:00, and DELETE on 2012-01-01 03:00:00

ID 2: ADD on 2012-01-01 00:00:00, DELETE on 2012-01-01 01:00:00, REVIVE on 2012-01-01 04:00:00, EDIT on 2012-01-01 05:00:00

ID 3: ADD on 2012-01-01 00:00:00, EDIT on 2012-01-01 03:00:00

How do I query the table to get following result:

Table C

```
NO       DESC
2        Two
3        Three
```

What I want to do is: to query the Table A that not having DELETE action at the last transaction time so I get only the active ID

I tried to do inner join but got stuck on how to omit ID that having delete action at the last transaction time. Any suggestion/comment would be appreciated.

Comment: Is `NO` primary key? Is it in order of `DATETIME`?

Comment: @KubaWyrostek Table A primary key is ID column and Table B primary key is NO column (which is for transaction index). it means that Table B will always be in DATETIME order. btw i'm using postgres

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this

```
select ID, DESC
from A join (
select id, action, rank() over (partition by id order by datetime desc) ranking
from B
) B on (B.ranking = 1 and B.id = A.id and B.action <> 'DELETE')
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming than `NO` is `TableB`'s primary key, ordered according to `DATETIME`:

```
select 
  TableA.ID, TableA.DESC
from TableA inner join 
  (select ID, max(NO) as MaxNO from TableB group by ID) as MaxNOs
    on TableA.ID = MaxNOs.ID
      inner join TableB on MaxNOs.ID = TableB.ID and MaxNOs.MaxNO = TableB.NO
where
  TableB.ACTION <> 'DELETE'
```